# 301 Redirect On Root Query Params

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I have tried several examples of how to do this but nothing is working and I fear it is because the query string is part of the base URL.

Here is what I would like to do:

> Redirect http://example.com/?from=TEST_1 -> http://example.com/foo
>
> Redirect http://example.com/?from=TEST_2 -> http://example.com/bar

Here is what I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} from=TEST_1
RewriteRule (.*) /foo [L,R=301]
```

Unfortunately the above rule has no impact.  If I change the rule to something static (see below) it works great:

```
Redirect 301 /foo /bar
```

Is there something special I need to do in order to check the query string value when it's part of the root domain request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these 2 rules as your very first rules just below `RewriteEngine` line.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^from=TEST_1$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /foo? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^from=TEST_2$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /bar? [L,R=301]
```

- `?` at the end of target URI is used to discard previous query string from target.
- `^/?$` is the regex to match landing page only.